# How to use lambda function to package this pointer and member functions into static functions?

Tags: c++, class, lambda, pointer-to-member

I need to use a member function as a callback function.

In python, it can be done like this:

```
CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int)
cb = CALLBACK(self.func)
```

But `cb=(callback_t)this->func;` doesn't compile in c++.

I wrap it with a lambda function, but it still doesn't compile.

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(int);
callback_t cb;

class A {
public:
    int i = 0;

    A() {
        cb = reinterpret_cast<callback_t>([this](int i2) mutable { func(i2); });
    }

    void func(int i1) {
        i = i1;
    }
};

int main() {
    A aa;
    cb(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change your callback_t definition to `typedef std::function<void(int)> callback_t;` and get rid of the reinterpret_cast

Comment: A capturing lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for the reply, now this code snippet works. But after I pass `cb` as a parameter to the library, it still doesn't work.
`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

Comment: I can't see what's going on in the library️

Comment: You don't mention or show anything about any library, so it is hard to say what is going on, but if the library just takes a function pointer as a callback (instead of a std::function), you'll need to do something else.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yes, it is a function pointer, the parameter I actually pass is &cb.

Comment: `&cb` is not a function pointer, so that won't work.  Since `cb` is a global var, you could write a small function that just calls `cb` with the argument it is passed, and pass a pointer to that to the library, but that gets tricky to manage if you want multiple callbacks.

Comment: @ChrisDoddHow to deal with different instances of the class when using a global variable?